# Totally antisymmetric Riemann tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Is it possible for a Riemannian manifold to have a non-vanishing Riemann tensor that is totally antisymmetric in the four indices?  Of course, the antisymmetry would imply that the Ricci tensor vanishes, i.e. the manifold is Ricci flat.

Comment: I think the first Bianchi identity would imply that R is identically zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Riemannian curvature tensor $R$ is defined via $R(X,Y,Z,W) = g(R(X,Y)Z,W)$, where $g$ is a Riemannian metric. If $R$ was totally skew-symmetric, the first Bianchi identity would imply
\begin{align*}
0 & = R(X,Y,Z,{}\cdot{})+R(Y,Z,X,{}\cdot{})+R(Z,X,Y,{}\cdot{}) \\
& = 3R(X,Y,Z,{}\cdot{}) \\
& = 3g(R(X,Y)Z,{}\cdot{}).
\end{align*}
Non-degeneracy of the metric $g$ would then give $R(X,Y)Z = 0$ for all $X,Y,Z$, i.e. $R=0$.